# Setting Toolbar in a fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, fragment, toolbar

I have a toolbar in my fragment that I need to set the activity's action bar, however, I get null whenever I call getSupportActionBar() method, anyone can help?

**My activity:**

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

    Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, fragment).commit();

  }

}
```

**Style.xml** the activity is using the `AppTheme.NoActionBar` theme

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**Fragment code:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

DrawerLayout drawer;
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setupToolbar();

    return view;
}


public void setupToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
  }
}

 ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar(); this line in the fragment will always return null.
```

Comment: You should call setupToolbar() in onActivityCreated or onAttach.

Comment: `toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` – You're looking for the `Toolbar` in the `Activity`. If it's in the `Fragment`'s layout, that's going to end up null. Look for it in the `View` you're inflating for the `Fragment` – `toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`.

Comment: ya exactly @Mike M. i missed that :)

Comment: Change your code from :                                                                       
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
  toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);                                                                                                                                           
To:                                                                                           
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
 toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

Comment: Thank you @MikeM. that solved the problem.